# Is there any way using which I can connect to 1010 data from Talend?

Tags: talend, 1010data

I want to connect to 1010 data using talend. But there are no predefined components for it in talend. So is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can connect to 1010 data using Talend Data Integration studio or ESB.  1010 exposes a web services API (there is plenty of documentation around but you can see this link https://www2.1010data.com/documentationcenter/prod/XMLAPI/XMLAPI.pdf)

Talend DI contains tREST_Cleint and tESBConsumer components for this purpose.  They can be used to interface with virtually any REST or SOAP web service API.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will try this out

Comment: if you are successful then please mark the question as answered.  thanks

Comment: Its working..Now I am able to read the data at least through Talend. Thanks